# Android: Background color on custom button not set correctly pre Lollipop

Tags: android, android-custom-view

When I use a standard button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
    style="@style/LoginButtonsStyle"
    android:text="@string/login.anmelden"
    android:theme="@style/CrGreenButton"/>
```

Style:

```
<style name="LoginButtonsStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/login_btn_height</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/login_buttons_bottom_margin</item>
</style>
```

Theme:

```
<style name="CrGreenButton">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/CrGreen</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/CrGreen</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/CrGreen</item>
</style>
```

everything works fine and the background color gets set on each api level 16+

But when I use my custom Button (written in kotlin, needed for a custom font)

```
open class CheckrobinButton : Button {

val fontPath = "fonts/CoreSansG55.otf"

constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
    init()
}

constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : super(context, attributeSet) {
    init()
}

constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr) {
    init()
}

constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes){
    init()
}

private fun init() {
    typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, fontPath)
}

}
```

the backgroundcolor is only set on API21+ (Lollipop) devices. On pre lollipop devices, the button stays in the standard grey color.

Why?

Comment: can you post the code of style and theme which you are using for the Button.

Comment: added theme and style to it!

Comment: can you try setting the attribute android:background directly to the Button instead of setting it in theme.

Comment: That works, but then the ripple effect is gone ...

Comment: You can use ?attr/selectableItemBackground as background for default ripple

Comment: To have different background color and also the ripple, refer my answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/36915339/4586742

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [AppCompat](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat), you need to extend [AppCompatButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatButton.html), rather than `Button` if you want to use the custom formatting and coloring prior to Lollipop with a custom class, as explained in the [Android Support Library 22.1 blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html).