# Material Design Button without Shadow

Tags: android, button, material-design, flat

I recently started android development and I am struggling a bit.
I read different articles and tutorials on creating drawables etc.

---

**Current Situation**

I have created the following buttons:

[image: Social Login Buttons]

Using the following code:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/login_btn_facebook"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_btn_login_facebook"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:text="Continue with Facebook"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        app:backgroundTint="#3b5998"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/login_btn_google"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_btn_login_google"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:text="Continue with Google"
        app:backgroundTint="#ffffff" />
```

---

Now I actually just need a minor change:
I do not want to have the elevation. I want the buttons to be "flat", and only show the shadow effect when clicked.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thank you already!

---

**UPDATE:**
I need to target **API Level 19** as a minimum SDK version.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720524/styling-a-appcompatbutton-in-v21-to-have-no-shadow-and-corner-radius-of-zero) seems to achieve what you want

Comment: Is your query resolved?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have two alternatives to do that:

1. By adding an XML attribute to your XML Button:

Try this: `android:stateListAnimator="@null"`

2. By adding another XML attribute, if the previous alternative has not worked:

Add this `style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"` to your XML Button according [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html).

[image]

Let me know if it doesn't work!

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I forgot to mention that I need to target SDK Level 19 as a minimum SDK version. I updated my question accordingly. Unfortunately the "stateListAnimator" attribute is not available there. If I use the borderless style, the background disappears completely.

Comment: @JDC I have edited my post with an image I took after I set minSdkversion to 19, it still works.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used the `stateListAnimator` attribute. This works.

Comment: anyone experiencing a weird bug with this? Setting stateListAnimator to null makes the button invisible

Answer (score 1):

Add the following attributes in your layout XML to remove shadows:

```
android:elevation="0dp"
android:translationZ="0dp"
```

This will make your layout look like:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/login_btn_facebook"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_btn_login_facebook"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:translationZ="0dp"
    android:text="Continue with Facebook"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    app:backgroundTint="#3b5998"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/login_btn_google"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_btn_login_google"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:translationZ="0dp"
    android:text="Continue with Google"
    app:backgroundTint="#ffffff" />
```

Read [here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I forgot to mention that I need to target SDK Level 19 as a minimum SDK version. I updated my question accordingly. Unfortunately the attributes to write about are not available there..

Comment: It will work if you keep your `targetSdkVersion 21` or above.

Comment: You are getting the shadow on a KitKat phone?

Comment: Hello again, unfortunately your suggestion does not work, the shadows are still there. Tested on API Level 23. as far as I have seen the `AppCompatButton` does not propagate the `elevation` & `translationZ` attribute.